# How to make an exe from Windows XP, Access 2000 run on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, microsoft-access

I have an exe from my college days, created on windows xp, and it used an access database of unknown version of that time. I tried opening it in my current PC, which is Windows 10, with Office 2019. But this office version is not compatible with the mdb file.Gives error: "Error number 3706 Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

Comment: Probably easiest; hunt down a copy of XP install media and install it in a Virtual Machine, then set it all up in there. (Need to get installers and bypass license-stuff, yes)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1)
The windows Xp executable is most-likely a 32-bit exe, please check if you have a 32-bit or 64-bit Office 2019 running. Taskmanager->Details->Select Columns (on the Column header) -> Check the Platform checkbox to see if an application is 32 or 64 bit.

I would test installing the 32-bit Access Runtime for Office.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9

Option 2)
You could use [DependencyWalker](https://dependencywalker.com/) to check the exe what dlls are missing and then try to determinate which microsoft package may include the missing files